# How to set default value for entity attribute with symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony, enums, doctrine-orm

I want to set a default value for an attribute called "status" in my entity called "Book" :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=BookingRepository::class)
 */
class Booking
{
    const STATUS = [
        0 => 'Pending',
        1 => 'Canceled',
        2 => 'Confirmed',
        3 => 'Approved',
    ];


    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, options={"default": "Pending"})
     */
    private $status = self::STATUS[0];


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getStatus(): ?string
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    public function getBookingStatus(): ?string
    {
        return self::STATUS[$this->status];
    }

    public function setStatus(string $status): self
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }


 
}
```

I declared a STATUS array with key/value to define a choice or enum type and I want to set the default value of $status as Pending ! is what I did right or need to do something else ?

Comment: if the interpreter doesn't complain, it's alright I guess? ;o)

Comment: Not really much point in doing what you are doing.  Consider something like CONST STATUS_PENDING = 0;

Comment: Adding to the comment of @Cerad, also I would initialise the default value  on the __contruct (). $this->status = self::STATUS_PENDING

Comment: @Albeis means `public function __construct() {}`